# what does the Values in mifare 1k classic sector and block do?

Tags: nfc, mifare

I was messing around with a mifare classic card that already has certain values in it. Its being use as arcade credits in my school.

The values are in sector 2 block 1 and block 2. each having 32bytes of hexdecimal. While i was messing with the values i realised that Sector 2 block 1 controls the amount of credit that the card has while sector 2 block 2 doesn't really do anything.

But if i were to change it to 32 bytes of 0 or 32bytes of F, the card doesnt work.

So i'm curious as to what block 2 does or how does mifare values/operation work.

Answer (score 2):

It's application-specific. It might be some MAC of the credit stored in the other block, to detect unapproved alterations ;)